# Is there a way to manually run cron with Drush?

Tags: drush, cron

I want to be able to accomplish this:
http://mywebsite.com/admin/reports/status/run-cron

But it should be done through the Drush interface.

Can any one help me out ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can try [`drush core-cron`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/core/core:cron/)

> $ drush help core-cron
> Run all cron hooks in all active modules for specified site.
>
> Aliases: cron

Comment: Does it execute https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_cron/7.x too?

Comment: @meen It will run all `hook_cron()` implementations, so `system_cron()` will be called.  It is equivalent to running from from the admin UI or /cron.php

Answer (score 26):

You can use `drush core-cron` or just `drush cron`

If you wish to use drush to run cron from a crontab, it's best to run cron as the web server user, and supply it with additional arguments to make up the lack of a terminal and supply environment variables.

The drush documentation explains it best either at [docs/cron.html](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drush/plain/docs/cron.html) or run `drush topic docs-cron`.

Personally I use server wide site aliases so I omit `--root` and `--uri` and use `@some.site` instead for a single site. If you have defined group aliases, you can run cron on the whole group by using `@some.group`. More information on [site aliases](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php) if you are interested, otherwise `drush docs-aliases`.

Comment: Wish I could double up-vote for pointing me to `drush topic docs-cron`!

Answer (score 9):

You could use **drush core-cron** command that would run the cron .
For more detailing about the commands that drush provides us is there on https://drushcommands.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--quiet`

The `--quiet` flag will suppress these and other progress messages, again avoiding an unnecessary email message.